# Cheap two-way flight from Ukraine to Japan

Tags: air-travel, transit, japan, budget, ukraine

I want to visit Japan in April (supposedly from 11.04 to 25.04). All tickets from Ukraine cost more than $900, which is a lot for me. I would like to find tickets at least a little cheaper, including through other countries.

I will be satisfied with any airport in Ukraine (but preferably Kiev) and Japan. Maybe there is some website that can look for directions, transit and transfers in other countries?
It is even possible to fly from another country (for example Poland), but I do not know whether it is possible to do so with a visa obtained in Ukraine.

Comment: Have you checked [Google Flights](https://www.google.com/travel/flights?hl=en&gl=ru&tcfs=ChEKCC9tLzBkbHhqGgVNaW5zaxIrCggvbS8wM18zZBIFSmFwYW4aGAoKMjAyMC0wMy0xMRIKMjAyMC0wMy0yNSIYCgoyMDIwLTAzLTExEgoyMDIwLTAzLTI1UgJgAQ&ved=0ahUKEwiSvtW_ye3lAhXiwosKHZWMDt4QyJABCAooAg&ictx=2#flt=/m/02sn34.r/m/03_3d.2020-03-11*r/m/03_3d./m/02sn34.2020-03-25;c:USD;e:1;p:90000.2.USD;sd:1;t:e&tcfs=ChEKCC9tLzBkbHhqGgVNaW5zaxIrCggvbS8wM18zZBIFSmFwYW4aGAoKMjAyMC0wMy0xMRIKMjAyMC0wMy0yNSIYCgoyMDIwLTAzLTExEgoyMDIwLTAzLTI1UgJgAQ)? The options are not that great but some are cheaper than $900.

Comment: JAL also [offers](https://www.jal.co.jp/inter/route/time/pdf_sites/europe_191027_200328.pdf) fairly cheap (~$280 x 2) direct flights from Moscow to Tokyo, but spending 12 hours on a train from Kyiv to Moscow (or 4 hours by plane with a layover in the middle) doesn't sound like a very fun thing to do, either...

Comment: Can you fly on different dates? The weekend is usually the most expensive day of the week.

Comment: @undercatsupportsMonica, yes, but me interested in April (you have March), there minimum the price 890 dollars.
Moscow is a great option for the price, but to get to Moscow is very long and I'm not sure about the political situation. I'll leave it as a backup, thank you.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, yes, I can, but I want the April 19-24 dates to be.

Comment: @BoberMod Oops, I totally didn't catch that! And unfortunately you are correct about Moscow, even though you should have visa-free entry to Russia as a Ukrainian citizen as of today, it's never certain what happens next month in the political chaos we live in currently, or what happens at the border.

Comment: That return flight might be cutting it close with Golden Week starting a couple of days later.

Comment: Checking Google Flights to Japan (i.e. put in Japan as the destination, it will check all airports) gets the price down to below 80000 yen if you fly Friday–Friday instead of Saturday–Saturday. I suggest playing around a bit with the different parameters there.

Answer (score -3):

According to Rome2Rio the cheapest flight between Ukraine and Japan is 270€ single, from Boryspil ([kbp](/questions/tagged/kbp)) to Chübu Centrair ([ngo](/questions/tagged/ngo)).

To find these flights you'll have to search regularly as prices can change every minute.

If you're under 26 you may be able to find youth tickets, which you can't find using normal flight search engines but only at the carriers own websites.

Comment: Exact prices are not terribly helpful, since they change all the time.  What airline/routing was offering the fare?

Comment: It is, but not on dates in April.